# How many tons of water is needed to surround ISS's living modules, so the rate of radiation exposure will be the same as on the surface of Earth?

Tags: radiation, space-station, water

If I understand correctly, it wasn't done because it's very expensive ($ per lbs) and there are no launch systems powerful enough for that?

Also, could you please provide formulas and calculations? I like those.

Comment: You might want to look at this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/what-thickness-depth-of-water-would-be-required-to-provide-radiation-shielding-i

Comment: See http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf found in an on-line version of the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/)'s pocket handbook and comments below [What type of software is used to make radiation shielding simulations for use in Space or Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31098/12102). See also this *Houston, We Have a Podcast* episode [Hazard 1: Radiation](https://www.nasa.gov/johnson/HWHAP/hazard-1-radiation) found in [this summary of five major risks](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30901/12102)

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't answer the question why there's no water shield on ISS.